# view composer target class not exist in host in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

hi I have view composer for views and everything works correctly but when to upload in host I've got target class does not exist.

in view composer

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\View\Composers;

use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use App\Models\File;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class FileComposer{

    public function compose(View $view){
        $view->with('files',File::orderBy('id','desc')->get());
    }
}
```

and in service provider

```
use App\Http\View\Composers;
use App\Http\View\Composers\FileComposer;
view::composer(['admin.files.index','layouts.master','index'], FileComposer::class);
```

Comment: did you run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: what is the name of the file this `FileComposer` class is in ... and we are assuming the 'target class not found' error is for `FileComposer`, yes?  include the full error message you are seeing

Comment: the file name is FileComposer.php

Comment: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Http\View\Composers\FileComposer] does not exist.

Comment: @Basharmal  yes i did